# WebBrowser automatic resize to remove div embedded scrollbars

Tags: scrollbar

I am using VB WebBrowser control to view specific web pages and screen shot it that have embedded div that displays table with lots of data rows, depending on the screen height a scroll bar of the div displays to scroll the data inside the div containing the table of data. Is there a way that I can automatically resize the WebBrowser Height to diaplay all the div/table data and to force remove the scrollbars of the div. The main purpose of this is to take a screen shot of the web browser whole page.

If I use a preset height for the web browser height, some pages have small amount of data in the div/table and show a long white empty area.

[image: This image show the embedded scrollbars]

Comment: aren't you going to run into problems no matter what? screen size is limited so you will have to scroll whenever the data is to big for your screen

Comment: The idea you can resize the height as you want, but what I want is to exactly fit the height, I am able to capture any height. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution in VB6 which you can do it in any language, `div__body` is the element with the contents:

```
If Not htmlDoc.getElementById("div__body") Is Nothing Then
    Set htmDiv = htmlDoc.getElementById("div__body")

    If htmDiv.scrollHeight > htmDiv.clientHeight Then
        WebBrowser.Height = WebBrowser.Height + PixelsToTwipsX(htmDiv.scrollHeight - htmDiv.clientHeight)
    End If

End If
```